# CSS position fixed strange rendering in chrome when scrolling

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, css-position

I have an element positioned fixed at the top of the screen, with a z-index of 100. When I scroll up the page in Chrome (V. 21.0.1180.82 on OS X and V. 21.0.1180.83 m on Windows) I notice a rendering problem which looks like this:

[image: position fixed chrome problem]

**UPDATE:**
I noticed that the rendering problem appears every time when the fixed element passes a new `<section>...</section>` during scrolling up. Chrome seems to have some issues related to HTML5 tags like `<section>...</section>` or `<nav>...</nav>`. Changing those to `<div>...</div>` solves the rendering problem, anyway I would still like to continue using HTML5 tags.

Does anybody know a "hack" to solve this problem?

Until then I will try to create a reproducible code sample and file a bug to [chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry).

Comment: Could you set up a jsFiddle? Or show a live example?

Comment: yaa actully..i also want jsFiddle or live example

Comment: Have you positioned it with top:0px? Please add some more info...

Comment: @bažmegakapa lots of code (not mine), rather difficult to show an example, I'll see what I can do to provide more detail.

Comment: @Lego Hard to tell without an example. Have not experienced it on any other browser/OS combination?

Comment: @bažmegakapa I've updated my question with a little more information - by now I've seen the problem acure in chrome on mac os x **and** windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the issue where elements with an opacity of 0 inside the fixed element. Setting those to `display: none` solved the problem.

Comment: How the hell does anyone find that solution. :D Thank you so much. I dealt with exactly the same issue and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly for Chrome latest browser version (55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit))
I have added:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```